# react dropzone uploader using custom request body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using react dropzone uploader as per the doc  to upload file to my server. I am adding some extra body params to formdata object as mentioned in the RDU component document here https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/api#getuploadparams
but it it always sending the request with standard request body of RDU.

my `getUploadParams` method looks like this

```
getUploadParams = ({ file, meta }) => {
        const data = new FormData()
        data.append('customFile', file)
        data.append('type', 'normal')
        return { data, url: uploadUrl }
    }
```

Any help how to send our own request formdata object?

Answer (score 1):

Correct way of using this

```
getUploadParams = ({ file, meta }) => {
    const body= new FormData()
    body.append('customFile', file)
    body.append('type', 'normal')
    return { url: uploadUrl, body }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return { url: uploadUrl,data }
```

maybe the order is failing you